# Highlight the matching cell text while filtering in angular UI-Grid

Tags: filter, highlight, matching

I am using angular UI grid and applied filter on my column, whenever i am entering any text on the filter box, the rows in the grid are filtered.
Now, i want to highlight the matching filter text in the cell as well. So ones i type anything on to the filter text box, the matching text for that cell is highlighted.